# why viewgroup invalidate does not make it's child's draw method be called back

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

I have made a custom `viewgroup` which has five `imageview`.

When I invalidate this `viewgroup`, why do all the "draw" methods of these `imageview` never get called back?

Doesn't the invalidate method traverse the `viewtree` from `viewrootiml`?

Comment: Is screen on when you call invalidate? It only force redraw if views are visible..

Comment: yes,screen is on.and the ondraw of imageview is not called back ,so does the draw .

Comment: I have cleaned up the formatting of your question as well as provided syntax highlighting and grammar correction.  This makes your question more presentable.